# Twitter's Bootstrap fixed-to-top navbar on scroll with in-page anchor links bouncing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a web page with a top horizontal navigation bar – it is Twitter's Bootstrap Fixed Top Navbar to be more precise – with a bottom-fixed position (actually it's not really fixed by CSS; see JavaScript below) so the navigation bar will first be visible at the bottom of the page and later displayed at the top of the page when scrolling (`position: fixed; top: 0`).

I have the navigation links set up with anchor tags to take the viewer to various places in the body of the page.  Unfortunately, sometimes it takes the user a bit too far down (especially if the user is at the top of the page and the navigation bar has not yet became fixed).

Take a look at my HTML structure:

```
<div id="landing"></div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#landing">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div id="section1"></div>
<div id="section2"></div>
<div id="section3"></div>
```

I'm using the following JavaScript to ensure that the navbar sticks to the top of the page after scrolling down:

```
function init() {
  nh = 50; // navbar height
  sh = $(window).height();
  ih = sh-nh;            
  $("#landing").css('height', ih+'px');
} 

function navbarState() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > ih) {
        $('.navbar').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
      } else {
        $('.navbar').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
      }
}

init();
navbarState();

$(window).on('load scroll resize orientationchange', function () {
    init();
    navbarState();
});
```

One can observe that repeatedly pressing the first anchor link causes a bouncing effect.  How can I prevent that?

My goal is to have the navigation scroll to the proper anchors, no matter whether the user is at the landing page or not.

Comment: *You are free to accept an answer, if it helped you and you don't have any more questions.  **:)**  Otherwise feel free to ask.*

Answer (score 0):

Why not using `navbar-fixed-bottom` as well?

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/y7soL4ej/

---

I added the mentioned class as default to `nav`. And modified minor things:

**CSS**

```
html, body, div#landing {
  height: 100%
}
section, [id*=section] {
  padding-top: 52px;
}
```

**JS**

```
function init() {
  nh = 50 + 2; // navbar height + 2x border width (top + bottom)
  sh = $(window).height();
  ih = sh-nh;            
  //$("#landing").css('height', ih+'px');
}

function navbarState() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > ih) {
        $('.navbar').removeClass('navbar-fixed-bottom').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
      } else {
        $('.navbar').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top').addClass('navbar-fixed-bottom');
      }
}

init();
navbarState();

$(window).on('load scroll resize orientationchange', function () {
    init();
    navbarState();
});
```

---

The jumpy behaviour: When the navbar is at the bottom in your example it is part of the dom flow - it seperates the *landing* div and the *section1* div by its height. As soon as it is clicked the browser jumps to the location, the navbar is then set as fixed at the top - and is no longer part of the flow (the both divs are no longer seperated by it). The *section* divs are therefore moved accordingly up to the *landing* div closing the gap. So clicking the same section anchor again will result in an additional jump, because the section was repositioned due to the *landing* div went from `position:static` to `position:fixed`.

That's an additional reason why I recommend to use `navbar-fixed-bottom`.

---

***Update***

new fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y7soL4ej/2/

I removed `.navbar-fixed-bottom` from HTML and JS as the navbar should not jump from bottom to top.
To make it smooth and avoid the earlier mentioned jumpy behaviour, I had to set it to absolute position.

some **CSS** needed to be added:

```
div#landing {
  padding-bottom: 72px;
  margin-bottom: -72px;
}

nav.navbar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; right: 0;
}
nav.navbar.navbar-fixed-top {
  position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: the navbar should indeed be part of the dom flow. I want it to get fixed at the top only after the user left the _landing_ div by scrolling down. If I set the navbar `navbar-fixed-bottom` it doesn't scroll with the content.

Comment: You set your *landing* container to a height per JS so that the navbar appears on the bottom of the page. What if the content of the *landing* container exceeds the viewport?